# How immutation happens with nested arrays in objects

Tags: javascript

```
let obj = {key : 'Add',arr : [0,2,3]}

let obj2 = Object.assign({},obj,{arr :obj.arr})
obj2.arr.pop()
console.log(obj)
console.log(obj2)
```

let us consider above example so I have to remove element from an array of obj2 then using pop is affecting both the arrays.

Comment: So what is the question? Why does `pop` affect both arrays?

Answer (score 0):

you should always `parse` and `stringify` object before making a copy,

`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj.arr))`

Object always keeps a reference, so if the child or parent object gets changed, both gets affected.

that is if `object a = object b`, then a change in `object b` affects `object a` also.

```js
let obj = {key : 'Add',arr : [0,2,3]}

let obj2 = Object.assign({},obj,{arr :JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj.arr))})
obj2.arr.pop()
console.log(obj)
console.log(obj2)
```

Comment: `you should always parse and stringify object before making a copy,` no, you shouldn't always do it. You *could* do it if you expect to mutate the object and also if the object mostly contains primitives aside from functions and symbols. Otherwise `{name: "bob", speak: () => console.log(this.name)}` will obliterate some of your data. If your object has a non-default and non-null prototype, you're also going to lose that.

Answer (score 0):

`Object.assign` does only a shallow copy, nested objects will be copied by reference.

You can stringify and then parse the object to make a deep clone, but be careful because if your object contains functions or circular references those will be lost during the serialization.

```js
let obj = {key : 'Add',arr : [0,2,3]}

let obj2 = Object.assign({},obj,JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({arr :obj.arr})))
obj2.arr.pop()
console.log(obj)
console.log(obj2)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are directly referencing 'arr' obj, which is not a copy but a reference to an array. To make it a copy just change obj2 as below and it will work fine for your case of pop()

```
let obj2 = Object.assign({}, obj, { arr : [...obj.arr] })
```